# ShareLatex and Texmaker

Tags: sharelatex

I am using the online editor ShareLatex  and texmaker in miktex. When I try to compile my source files from ShareLatex with texmaker it doesnt work. For example the nomenclature of symbols isnt working. Does anyone have experience with using the source code of ShareLatex with offline programs?
My OS is Windows 10.

Here is some if my code:
main.tex

```
\documentclass[diplomgeo,german,nomencl]{zihpub}

 \usepackage{setspace}


 \usepackage{subfiles}
 \usepackage{nomencl}
 \makenomenclature
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
    \lstset{basicstyle={\small \ttfamily}}

\usepackage{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{dinat}

\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

...

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\setnomenclmargin{1cm}
```

The complete tex.main file:
[tex.main](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11283715/texmainzumhochladen.txt.html)

And here is the *.cls stylesheet:

```
%Nomenclature
\if@nomencl
%  \if@german
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Symbolverzeichnis}
%  \else
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
%  \fi
%  \label{sec:Nomenclature}
  \printnomenclature[\@nomenclmargin]
\fi
```

The complete *.cls you can download as txt file from here:

[cls file](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11283590/clsDateizumHochladen.txt.html)

Comment: Have you installed all necessary packages for the code to run? Miktex often installs a small subset and installs the rest om the fly.

Comment: Btw how is the nomenclature made? Some constructions require you to run external programmes, something texmaker does not do by default

Comment: Texmaker asked me to install packages which the code requires. At least I think it did that.

Comment: Can you show us a small example code which will not run in your TeXMaker? That way, we might be able to tell, if you need to additional configure something?

Comment: ShareLaTeX is some intelligent piece of software that just knows what compilation steps are needed and in which order they have to be done. With texmaker, you are iin charge of making all needed packages available and call external programs if needed. This might be complicated for a beginner.

Comment: I edited my post and included some of the source code

Comment: is that *all* of the class file?

Comment: No. Only a part of it. With class file you mean cls file?

Comment: The cls file is huge. I cannot post it here. That's why I only postet a little part which includes the nomenclature of symbols.

Comment: And how exactly do you expect others to help if they do not have access to something we can compile and test. Isn't the class file downloadable from somewhere?

Comment: I uploaded it and edited my post

Comment: Please also make your doc example complete

Comment: I edited and included the link for the tex.main file

Comment: Before uploading, have you checked the copyright if you are allowed to distribute the class file? Have you checked if you ran all external programs that need to be run? If it works in sharelatex, this is the most likely case and has absolutely nothing to do with the class file.

Comment: The cls can be downloaded by everyone from the University Website. How do I know which external programs I should run?

Comment: You should read the documentation of package `nomencl`. [Wie kompiliere ich im Terminal](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3461/wie-kompiliere-ich-in-der-eingabeaufforderung-im-terminal) Since you seem to be an absolute beginner, maybe have a look at [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html)?

Comment: Actually I have worked with Latex ohne year ago. My script works perfectly with ShareLatex. So why would I start all over again?

Comment: Well, if it works with sharelatex, stick with it. Why go into all that trouble to make it run on your computer? You don't have to read an introduction, i was just assuming you are a starter based on the information you are giving and questions you are asking.

Comment: I' ll read the documentation.

Comment: By the way, if you want to ping somebody, write the @-sign and the name, you can auto-complete using tab => @ypennylane This way, the user gets notified. Since you are writing in german, maybe checkout golatex.de, a classical discussion forum without the annoying comment structure.